# Get the specific text inside span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the sample td for a dynamic table generated. 
I need to iterate through the tds to match the `'Data'` values and to check if its corresponding `'Result'`  value is populated or not.

If the `'Result'` is not populated , there will not be `span class="taglist"` element.

```
<td class="indent0"> 
    Data1 
    <span class="aspect-data"> 
        <span class="taglist">Result1</span> 
    </span>
<td class="indent0"> 
    Data2 
    <span class="aspect-data"> 
        <span class="taglist">Result2</span> 
    </span>
```

I have tried to iterate using the below code, which alerts all the `'Result'` values, but I need to get only the corresponding values of a `'Data'` given.

```
$('.indent0').each(function() {
    var celltext = $(this).html();  
    if (celltext = "Data1") {
        var spantext = $(this).find(".taglist").html();
        if (spantext != null) {
            alert(spantext);
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: `if (celltext = "Data1") ` is assigning ; what you need is `if (celltext =="Data1") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$('.indent0').each(function() {
    var celltext = $(this).contents().first()[0].textContent;  //this line has changed
    if (celltext == "Data1") {
        var spantext = $(this).find(".taglist").html();
        if (spantext != null) {
            alert(spantext);
        }
    }  
});
```

or

```
$('.indent0').each(function() {
    var celltext = $(this).contents()[0].nodeValue;  //this line has changed
    if (celltext == "Data1") {
        var spantext = $(this).find(".taglist").html();
        if (spantext != null) {
            alert(spantext);
        }
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that `DataX` is not wrapped in a specific element, so you'll need to grab the text node and check the text value of that against the value you're looking for.

Also note that you're using `=` for setting a value instead of `==` to compare a value in your `if` condition, and your HTML is missing some `</td>` tags. Try this:

```
$('.indent0').each(function() {
    var celltext = $(this).contents()[0].nodeValue.trim();
    if (celltext == "Data1") {
        var spantext = $(this).find(".taglist").html();
        if (spantext != null) {
            alert(spantext);
        }
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pqqmow8c/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) like following.

```js
$('.indent0').each(function () {
    var celltext = $(this).text().trim(); // change here
    if (celltext.startsWith("Data1")) {  // change here
        var spantext = $(this).find(".taglist").html();
        if (spantext != null) {
            alert(spantext);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="indent0">
            Data1
            <span class="aspect-data">
                <span class="taglist">Result1</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="indent0">
            Data2
            <span class="aspect-data">
                <span class="taglist">Result2</span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```